# can i add a new worker on-the-fly to my dyno on heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, worker, dyno

Is there a way to create new workers on a running dyno in heroku on-the-fly?

Without the need to edit .procfile and restart the dyno?

My scenario is a main worker who create some other workers.

Comment: Can you explain this scenario further? Why can't you create a Procfile entry for your various workers?

Comment: Because the worker will be generated dynamically... by user action... its make sense for you?

Comment: You can easily spawn new processes on your existing dyno, if that's what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @YoniRabinovitch I want to run a new worker on my dyno.. not a simple process... worker can be specified only in boot-time?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "worker"? If you mean a background process to which, for example, your main process delegates work, then you can spawn it dynamically at run time, when needed.